# What is the order of $e^{\large \frac{4\pi i}{5}}$ in the circle group $U_{20}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We talk about the Circle group.
What is the order of $e^{\large \frac{4\pi i}{5}}$?

The power is $\frac{4\pi i}{5}$ if it's not clear...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this question stems from your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555826/meaninig-of-a-symbol-at-the-circle-group), where you were talking about $\omega^{8}_{20}$ in the circle group of order $20$, recall that the circle group is cyclic, and so this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{20}$, the additive group of integers modulo $20$.

Now, we have that $\left(\omega^{8}\right)^5 = \omega^{40} = e^{4\pi i} = 1$, and $5$ is the least integer $k$ such that $(\omega^8)^k = 1$.  Hence  $\operatorname{ord}(\omega^8) = \operatorname{ord}(e^{4\pi i/5})= 5$.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot!
Now the things are more clearly!! Thank you!

Comment: @amWhy: That is excellent feedback! :=) +1